# codeigniter get time zone offset

Tags: php, datetime, codeigniter

i need to get the timezone offset value from the timezone data in codeigniter. Timezones i have are UM12, UM11, .... UTC.... UP10 UP11 UP12..... i need exact offset values. is there any direct method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$this->load->helper('date');

```
echo timezone('UM10'); //  will give -10
```

or try

```
print_r(timezone()); // List the entire timezone array
```

Hope this will help ;)